# C++: Get unique_ptr which owns row pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, row, unique-ptr

I have unique_ptr and a row pointer that the unique_ptr points to. How do I call release for unique_ptr using only row pointer rowPtr?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> uniqPtr = std::make_unique<int>(2);
    int* rowPtr = uniqPtr .get();

    // call .release for uniqPtr using only rowPtr
    
    return 0;
}
```

UPD:
I will clarify the question. I need uniqPtr to become empty using only rowPtr.

Comment: `uniqPtr` doesn't just point to the `int`, it *owns* it. It would be a bad situation if some entity external to `uniqPtr` could just force it to give up its ownership. (In the real world, we usually call this "theft".)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I call release for unique_ptr using only row pointer rowPtr?

You cannot. You can only release a unique pointer by calling the `release` member function on the unique pointer. You cannot use, nor do you need, the bare pointer to do that.

Comment: Do you know if there are ways to make uniqPtr empty without calling it?

Comment: @JoungCPPser As per my answer, there are no such ways.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Raw pointers do not participate in ownership. Nor shall they.

When you call `get` you are explicitly saying: "I want only a raw pointer. I do not want to interfere with ownership of the managed pointer".

Comment: Do you know if there are ways to make uniqPtr empty without calling it?

Comment: @JoungCPPser the whole purpose of `std::unique_ptr` is that `std::unique_ptr` is in control of lifetime of the pointed to object. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? It sound like you are fighting against `unique_ptr`and are facing a "problem" that you wouldnt have if you didnt use `unique_ptr` in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `int *p = uniqPtr.release()` to get the pointer without destroying it. `p` points still to a valid memory, but `uniqPtr` is no longer managing it.

You can also use `uniqPtr.reset(nullptr)` which would destroy the object and resets the `unique_ptr` to a `nullptr`. In this case `ptr` is no longer pointing to the object and the memory of that object has been freed.

In any case you can not use the raw pointer, managed by `uniqPtr`, to change the state of the `unique_ptr` object, because the raw pointer doesn't have any association with it, it's just managed by it.

Comment: Do you know if there are ways to make uniqPtr empty without calling it?

Comment: You can not. You can just assign a new pointer which is basically the same as `ptr.reset(new_ptr)`.